# How to select an element if a condition on a descendant of a common ancestor is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, jquery-selectors

I've got a page with multiple *div* elements of class 'container', ie:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="data"> 
        <a class="myclass" href="foo" origin="internal"> 123456789 </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="save" role="add" add="Save" remove="Remove"> Save </button>
        <button class="delete" role="add" remove="Discard" rel="nofollow"> Discard </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I select all buttons of class 'delete', but only if the *a* element had origin="internal"?

The common ancestor of both elements is the div of class "container".

Besides, how can I programmatically click on all those buttons on page load?

Comment: How do you bound the common ancestor level? At the end everything has the common ancestor `body`. So up to container?

Comment: Just edited the question. The common ancestor is the div element of class "container".

Comment: *Select element* and *programmatically click element* are kinda different tasks. What is your **exact** question? Also let us know what have you already tried and describe the issues you've faced with. For now it just seems like you want someone to do your job . That is not what SO should be used for

Comment: Sorry, I have not coded for the last 4 years and I now feel like a newbie... My intention was to select those buttons so that I could click on them. Not sure if that's a good approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter and map all containers:

```js
const result = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".container"))
     .filter(c => c.querySelector("a[origin=internal]"))
     .map(c => c.querySelector("button.delete"));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="data"> 
        <a class="myclass" href="foo" origin="internal"> A </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="save" role="add" add="Save" remove="Remove"> Save </button>
        <button class="delete" role="add" remove="Discard" rel="nofollow"> Discard A </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="data"> 
        <a class="myclass" href="foo" origin="external"> B </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="save" role="add" add="Save" remove="Remove"> Save </button>
        <button class="delete" role="add" remove="Discard" rel="nofollow"> Discard B </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="data"> 
        <a class="myclass" href="foo" origin="internal"> C </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="save" role="add" add="Save" remove="Remove"> Save </button>
        <button class="delete" role="add" remove="Discard" rel="nofollow"> Discard C </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

<sub>(Furthermore, i believe that jQuery should never be used.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, H.B! Nice solution. By the way, how can I programmatically click on all buttons returned by your filter&map solution?

Comment: @user2883935: Just add `.forEach(b => b.click())`.

Comment: Glab to help :) If you think this sufficiently answered the question you can click the checkmark outline at the left side of the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the buttons with `class="delete"` and then you can use an `if else statement`. For example:

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).parent().data('origin') == 'internal'){
        //do something
    }else{
       //do something else
    }
})
```

Comment: I've just edited the question again, as my next question is: how can I programmatically click on all those buttons?

Comment: Yes thats why i wrote this answer, how to click on those elements.